# Creating some part of UI for an existing C++ project in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, integration

I’ve a C++ project where some part of the UI is made in flex . I want to remove flex from my application with some alternatives. Right now I am investigating on using CEF which can be embedded in the application.

Please suggest me if going for Qt would be better option. Making complex UI as easily as possible is my requirement. I would also want integrating Qt in my existing project to be simple with flawless to-and-fro communication between existing C++ code and Qt. Since, I’ve no idea about Qt, hoping for an insight on this.

I need to support Windows and Mac OSX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qt fits your requirements (cross platform, easy, can make complex UIs, etc), but you will need to learn about Signals and Slots, and the event system used by Qt.

You can learn this through the tutorials and examples built into Qt, or by reading the amazing documentation.

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/tutorials.html

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/all-examples.html

(All of this information is easy to get to from the Welcome screen inside Qt Creator)

Detailed docs about how signals and slots and events work:

http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/4.8/signalsandslots.html

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/eventsandfilters.html

Hope that helps.